# Add HotKey to NSTextField

Tags: cocoa, hotkeys

I have some trouble with my `NSTextField` subclass. It's a textfield for input some message. And My application must send this message when my sub-textfield is a first responder and the user presses hotkey <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I can't use Carbon method `RegisterEventHotKey()` because many applications use this hotkey for the same action but my application intercepts it. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I subclassed NSApplication and override method

```
- (void) sendEvent:(NSEvent*) event {
    if ([event type] == NSKeyDown) {
        if (([event modifierFlags] & NSDeviceIndependentModifierFlagsMask) == NSCommandKeyMask) {
            if ([event keyCode] == 36) {
                if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(sendMessage:)]) {
                    [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(sendMessage:) withObject:nil];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [super sendEvent:event];
}
```

in info.plist I wrote that this sub-NSApplication class is a Principal class. It works!

Answer (score 14):

In the text field delegate, you can follow all “standard” commands are sent to the control. Then, once you meet a command `noop:`, test for current key combination. If it is `Command-Enter`, do your thing. Something like this should work:

```
@interface VCEAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSTextFieldDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *textField;
@end

// .m
@implementation VCEAppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    self.textField.delegate = self;
}

- (BOOL)isCommandEnterEvent:(NSEvent *)e {
    NSUInteger flags = (e.modifierFlags & NSDeviceIndependentModifierFlagsMask);
    BOOL isCommand = (flags & NSCommandKeyMask) == NSCommandKeyMask;
    BOOL isEnter = (e.keyCode == 0x24); // VK_RETURN
    return (isCommand && isEnter);
}

- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textView:(NSTextView *)textView
                          doCommandBySelector:(SEL)commandSelector {
    if ((commandSelector == @selector(noop:)) &&
        [self isCommandEnterEvent:[NSApp currentEvent]]) {
        [self handleCommandEnter];
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

- (void)handleCommandEnter {
    NSLog(@"Do something on Command-Enter");
}

@end
```

Comment: Glad you worked it out! Though in terms of class design my solution is  more decoupled. If you are working on a comparably big app, please ensure that you really want to subclass NSApplication and micro-manage that particular event. Good luck :)

Comment: This worked for me except using the delegate `- (BOOL)textView:(NSTextView *)textView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)commandSelector` instead of `- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textView:(NSTextView *)textView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)commandSelector`. Thanks!

Comment: Great solution, thanks. To suppress a warning in Xcode 13, we changed `commandSelector == @selector(noop:)` to `commandSelector == NSSelectorFromString(@"noop:")`